# Regular expression to extract substring of digits between markers

Tags: regex

I'd like to extract the second to right most 6 digits between a ; and ? from a string.  Here's some examples:

```
;10001080812?    --> 108081

;0009242340?     --> 924234
```

Notice "second to right most" because the last digit is not wanted.
It would be nice if it was easy to change the number of digits I wanted to extract.

This is what I've got so far, it gets me the digits excluding the last digit

```
/(?<=\;)(.*?)(?=\d\?)/
```

But what I really want is just the rightmost 6 digits of this (or X digits).

Comment: Are there only digits ever between the `;` and `?`?

Comment: C# and yes, digits should only be between ; and ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regular expression

```
\d{6}(?=\d\?)
```

Answer (score 0):

`^;[0-9]*[0-9]{n}[0-9]{m}\?$`

The regular expression above reads `n` digits but leaves `m` digits at the end (which won't be read).